# Clearing values of a composite component in a reusable form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I have a composite component:

```xml
<ui:component
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<cc:interface componentType="compositeLocalDate">
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="org.joda.time.LocalDate" shortDescription="The bean value" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="days" type="java.lang.Boolean" shortDescription="Add the days input question" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="disabledBy" type="java.lang.Boolean" shortDescription="Disable the component" required="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="limitFuture" type="java.lang.Integer" shortDescription="How many future months to allow based on this number of days in the future. default = all" required="false" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation><!-- 
 --><div class="dateInput">
        <h:inputText autocomplete="off" binding="#{cc.day}" id="day" maxlength="2" styleClass="compositeDay" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabledBy}" a:placeholder="dd" a:pattern="[0-9]{1,2}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.days}" />

        <h:selectOneMenu binding="#{cc.month}" id="month" styleClass="compositeMonth" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabledBy}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Month" itemDisabled="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownsBean.months(cc.attrs.limitFuture)}" var="item" itemValue="#{item.name}" itemLabel="#{item.customerDescription}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:inputText autocomplete="off" binding="#{cc.year}" id="year" maxlength="4" styleClass="compositeYear" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabledBy}" a:placeholder="yyyy" a:pattern="[0-9]{4}" />
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

That is used in a form:

```xml
<cc:compositeLocalDate id="dob" value="#{myBean.aList[formBean.selectedIndex].dateOfBirth}" days="true" />
```

The form is reused several times to add more items to the list. When an add button is clicked the form is cleared:

```java
protected void loadNewItem(MyBean myBean, FormBean formBean){
    myBean.add(new Person());
    formBean.reset();
    formBean.setSelectedIndex(myBean.getAList.size()-1);
}
```

Here's the FormBean reset method:

```java
public void reset(){
    name = null;
    //other code that resets Members of FormBean
}
```

The problem I have is that everything is clearing from the form when adding another person except the composite component which retains the values entered for the previous person. I assume this is because they are stored in the `CompositeLocalDate` java class:

```java
public abstract class GenericCompositeLocalDate extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {
    private UIInput day;
    private UIInput month;
    private UIInput year;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GenericCompositeLocalDate.class);

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

        if (getValue() != null && isValid()) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(((LocalDate) getValue()).toDate());

            month.setValue(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
            year.setValue(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
            boolean checkDays = (Boolean) getAttributes().get("days");
            if (checkDays) {
                day.setValue(String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
            }
        }
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue() {
        boolean checkDays = (Boolean) getAttributes().get("days");
        return (checkDays ? day.getSubmittedValue() : "01") + "/" + month.getSubmittedValue() + "/" + year.getSubmittedValue();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object submittedValue) {
        LOG.debug("investigate. submittedValue is \"" + submittedValue + "\"");
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
            format.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            format.setLenient(false);
            return new LocalDate (format.parse((String) submittedValue));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public UIInput getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(UIInput day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public UIInput getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(UIInput month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public UIInput getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(UIInput year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

How can I clear these values?